# Changing structure within a TFS solution in active projects?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfs, projects-and-solutions

We have a solution containing about 30 projects that is ogranized in a given catalog structure(in the solution). On the filesystem the projects is however located all around the place so now I need to clean this up. There is however several problems with this :

1. If I move a project on the filesystem it will be unavailable in the solution, to solve this I will have to remove the project and then add existing to the solution. Im not sure how this will effect the TFS history that most not get lost?
2. There is people working ont these projects and if thay are moved when checking in there will probably be big problems?

So how do I solve this changes without stalling any other development within this solution?

Comment: Which TFS version and Visual Studio version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it quickly, or at least each action should be quick.

If you need to move a Project to the correct location you should:

1. Notify all developers you are moving a project and not to check out.
2. Move the Project folder
3. Open the Solution file in notepad and change the location reference to the project
4. Save and checkin.
5. Instruct all other users to get latest.

Do that for each move, slowly over a few days and you should be good. A big bang move is also possible but if you have 50 Devs then it is costly.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the same thing. 
Our Solutions were and are organized in this way:

```
TeamProject
    App1
        DevFolder (contains branches of BranchTest)
            BranchOfDev1
            BranchOfDev2
            BranchOfDev3
            BranchOfDev4
        TestFolder
            BranchTest
        ProdFolder (contains branches of BranchTest)
            BranchProdV1
            BranchProdV2
            BranchProdV3
    App2
        Dev...
        Test...
        Prod...
    ...
```

- This is just one solution with several dependencies on existing Projects in other Folders/branches etc..
- Everything branches from the TestBranch. Devs Merge into Test, ProdVersions are branched from Test.
- The TestBranch contains the newest Version of the application
- The devs only develop in their own dev-branches and when they are done they merge to the TestBranch

I did the move in this way:

- Create a New Team Project in TFS
- Create the new structure according to the existing one (the branch-concept is ok)
- DEV-STOP. Everybody must Merge into the TestBranch
- At one point *moved* the TestBranch to the new Location.
- Moved all dependencies as well
- **Edited the .sln by Hand with the new Locations of dependencies, check that in** (answer to your question)
- DELETE all the DevBranches
- Create new DevBranches in the new structure
- Everybody deletes their local Workspace, redownload from the new TeamProject
- Cloak the old Folders. DO NOT DELETE them if you want to Keep the history!
- Everybody should be happy now

Edit: We are now in the process of creating nuget packages for all the external and common dependencies. This way in the future we'll be able to update the core/dependencies without breaking anything that uses earlier Versions of them.